# Spring 3 MVC ContentNegotiatingViewResolver example

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller not found error occuring while running this example from MyKong

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Kindly help me out

Comment: is spring-oxm on your project's classpath?

Comment: Can you elaborate when you say is spring-oxm on the projects classpath.So is there a dependency i should in iclude in POM or a plugin which I should install.Sorry I am quite new to Spring MVC.

Comment: yes, you need [one of these](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-oxm%22) as dependency in your pom.xml, depending on the version of spring you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

where `${spring.version}` is the spring framework version you're using

Comment: Thanks for your response.But its not working even when I add the dependency to the POM.xml file.It still shows the same error.

Comment: @user1512102 are you sure you recompiled and redeployed the application?

Comment: Hey Thanks its working now But the JSON and RSS views are not working correctly as expected.With JSOn there arises an alert which  says do you want save the file or find the program online.I have no idea about what the alert means.

Comment: check the content type of the response, but generally it's a browser configuration problem